# Como formatar o número de uma célula no excel para o tipo horas através do OpenPyxl (Python)?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, formatação, openpyxl

Opa, tudo bem com vocês?

Então, estou desenvolvendo uma API teste em Python que quando é chamada, tem de me retornar um arquivo em Excel com dados pré-definidos. Um desses dados é uma variável de hora que deve estar formatada no respectivo formato no arquivo Excel, como nesse exemplo:

[image: Formatação certa das horas]

Porém, mesmo formatando a célula por meio do método ".number_format", o dado ainda se apresenta como personalizado como podem ver abaixo.

[image: Foto do exemplo de excel gerado pela API]

O código que fiz segue abaixo:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
import datetime
from src.functions.errors import return_error

class classRelatorioExcel:

    def execute(self, req, resp, filters, tabs, identifier):
        try:
            excel_filename = 'Relatorio.xlsx'

            wb = Workbook()
            ws = wb.active
            ws.title = 'teste'

            ws['A1'] = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
            ws['A1'].number_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'

            ws['B1'] = datetime.time(21, 43, 50)
            ws['B1'].number_format = 'hh:mm:ss'

            wb.save(filename=excel_filename)

            output = save_virtual_workbook(wb)

            resp.set_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" % excel_filename)
            resp.data = output
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'error: {error}')
            return return_error(resp, 'Erro ao tentar gerar relatório.', 500)
```

Tem alguma maneira de formatar a célula para que fique no formato de horas ao invés do personalizado?

Comment: Cara, eu tentei com os diversos formatos para time que aparecem aqui:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html
E eu nao consegui fazer o excel identificar como "Hora", mas de uma olhada aí, talvez ajude

Comment: Psé, eu também tentei esses formatos e não deu certo. Acho q talvez seja padrão do Excel definir como personalizado quando formatamos para "Hora"

Comment: Não usei muito esse módulo, muito menos esse método .number_format(),
mas já olhou isso aqui?
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html
tenta:
ws['B1'].number_format = 19

Comment: O que quer dizer com "formato de horas"?

Answer (score 0):

Olá Vinícius o openpyxl quando você insere um padrão ele acaba o adicionando aquela lista de personalização do excel. O que aconselho você a fazer é criar um layout contendo o formato que deseja, ai quando você for salvar seu arquivo, você o salva com um outro nome para não alterar seu layout.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="Bases/Layout.xlsx")
```

Ao terminar o seu código finalize com um:

```
wb.save(filename="Processado/Nome-do-seu-arquivo.xlsx")
```

Já trabalhei com projetos que precisavam ter as colunas com padrões determinados e minha solução foi essa.